# Counting the number of allowed energy states of a particle in a 3D box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, density-of-states

I am reading a book on Modern Physics by Thornton and Rex. I am looking at a particle in a 3-dimensional infinite square well potential (particle in a box). If the particle is a photon, its energy can be written as $E = \frac{hc}{2L} \sqrt{n_1^2 + n_2^2 + n_3^2}$ , where $n_i$ are integer quantum numbers which can also be viewed as the coordinates of a number space. Next, $r$ is defined as $r^2 = n_1^2 + n_2^2 + n_3^2$. The book says that the number of allowed energy states within "radius" $r$ is $N_r = 2(\frac{1}{8})(\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3)$, where the factor $1/8$ comes from being restricted to the octant where $n_i$ have positive values only and the factor of $2$ is because there are two possible photon polarizations.

Question: Since the volume $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ is a continuous object, how can it "count" the number (which is discrete) of energy states within radius $r$?

Answer (score 1):

It is analogous to drawing a circle on a chess board. For any given size of circle, there will be a number of points inside it which are the centres of squares on the board.

In the specific case you have given, for a given value of r there will be a set of values of n1, n2 and n3 for which the square root of the sum of their squares is less than or equal to r, ie which correspond to points inside the surface defined by r.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, $N_r$ is not usually an integer so it is not an exact count of the energy states with $n_1^2 +n_2^2+n_3^2 \le r^2$. It is an approximation based on calculating the volume of the sphere with radius $r$ and assuming there are on average $2$ energy states per unit volume in one octant of this sphere.

Comment: Worth noting, this approximation gets better as the volume of the box increases. For a macroscopic box it's pretty much exact in the photon case.